# Script .bat for eliminate all files and folders (excluding some) on Windows desktop

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7

I need to manage multiple Windows 7 desktop computers. I need to delete all files from desktop. Having the possibility to run a command by prompts, I have thought about writing a bat script to delete all files and folders, except for lnk files (for preserving software link).
I also need to exclude some folders that unfortunately on each computer have a variable name (such as FOLDER01, FOLDER02, FOLDER03, ...) for which I would just delete the content.

This is the code that I wrote helping myself on the web.

```
@Echo OFF

For %%# in (
    "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\*"
) Do (
    If /I not "%%~x#" EQU ".lnk" (
        Del /Q "%%#"
    )
)

FOR /D %%# IN (
    "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\*"
) DO (
    IF /I not "%%#" EQU "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\FOLDER" (
        rmdir "%%#" /s /q
    )
)
```

It works well, I can exclude folders with specific names (eg FOLDER), but unfortunately I could not exclude folders that have a variable name (such as FOLDER01, FOLDER02, ..)

How can I modify this script to automatically exclude folders called FOLDERxx?

PS. xx ∈ [0,1, ... 99] of couse

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: One approach would be to use the FINDSTR command and evaluate it's errorlevel, by calling directly after the FINDSTR command something like ``IF NOT %errorlevel% == 0 (echo here I do some action)``

Comment: Can you provide a FINDSTR code sample please?